# For orthogonal vectors $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $x$ has norm $4$ and $y$ has norm $4$ then what is the norm of $x+y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For orthogonal vectors $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $x$ has norm $4$ and $y$ has norm $4$ then what is the norm of $x+y$?

Comment: x,y and x+y are all coplanar (the belong to the same plane). So you can use Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the vectors are orthogonal, they meet at a right angle, so we have

$$|| x+y || = \sqrt{||x||^2 + ||y||^2}$$

by the Pythagorean theorem.